# Calculate the degree of similarity between 2 not equal integer arrays

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to calculate the similarity between 2 array of integer data which they have not the same length. I used a method called **jaccard similarity** which depend on Intersection and union. This is the using code to get similarity using jaccard

```
        //jaccard similarity
        var CommonNumbers = from a in A.AsEnumerable<int>()
                            join b in B.AsEnumerable<int>() on a equals b
                            select a;
        double JaccardIndex = (((double)CommonNumbers.Count()) /
                               ((double)(A.Count() + B.Count())));
```

but I've noticed that this method is not good for my case as it depend on the CommonNumbers between the groups and it is not good for my case

Can i use **Cosine similarity** in case of not equal 2 arrays ?

Any tips for better ways to calculate the degree of similarity between two not equal array of integer numbers ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you need to join lists() where a != b, a straight join will only get all a items and b items the are contained in a.  Not the items in b that are not in a.  So to get all b items you need to use a left outer join.  See msdn examples : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Can you pad the shorter one?

Comment: Is the array a signal or random variable?

Comment: the array has a specific length and contain known integer numbers

Comment: You have to be the one to define what "similarity" means for your use case. What is the goal?